# how to get all children models belonging to a certain parent model (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am struggling with getting names of the Classes(Models) from a parent instance.
Below is the situation;

```
<Parent>
  has_many :child_a
  has_many :child_b
<ChildA>
  belongs_to :parent
<ChildB>
  belongs_to :parent
```

I want to get what models the instance has like,

```
@parent = Parent.find(1) 
@parent.hoge
=> [ChildA, ChildB]   (ChildA & ChildB are class names)
```

Could you tell me if there is some method like above or some ways similar to that.
I would appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Parent.reflect_on_all_associations
```

This will return an array of `ActiveRecord::Reflection`. From that you could just for example map the class name and constantize them for your class type via:

```
Parent.reflect_on_all_associations.map do |association|
    association.options[:class_name].constantize
end
```

Comment: I really appreciate both of you guys, Dharman, and Erwin !!